# Pandas: how to apply a transformation to each row?

Tags: python, pandas

Initially I have a row and I would like to setup some new columns for each row following some non-trivial algorithm.

I can do it that way:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[df.index == index, 'NEW_COL'] = ...
```

but it is rather clumsy. Is there  a way to befine *lambda row -> row* and apply it to the dataframe?

Comment: you mean `df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)`?

Comment: Does the next row depend on the previous row's new column?  A simplified version of the non-trivial algorithm would help... Unless @EdChum's already answered your question.

Comment: the `df.apply` option works very simply for when only 1 data column is needed. Can you give us a hint of this non-trivial algorithm?

Answer (score 8):

I think you want something like:

```
def func(row):
    row.(here you can access any column of your dataframe) 

    return (the value in here will go to the 'NEW_COL' you are defining)

df['NEW_COL'] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

If you want something any more specific provide more details in your post